# Error while Inserting null value using Java Prepared Statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, null, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert null value using java prepared statement, Following is the Code:

```
VendorDto c; //as parameter

PreparedStatement pstmt = null,
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlString);
pstmt.setInt(1, cvID);
pstmt.setString(2, c.getFirstName());
pstmt.setString(3, c.getLastName());
if(c.getDateInput()==null || c.getDateInput().trim().equals("")) {
    pstmt.setNull(4, Types.TIMESTAMP);
  }else {
    pstmt.setDate(4, cinfo.string2date(c.getDateInput()));
}
int num = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Following is the generated pstmt value:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: insert into bca_clientvendor(ClientVendorID, FirstName, LastName, DateInput)  values(911,'ATM','Hasan',** BYTE ARRAY DATA **)
```

setNull is returning the value ** BYTE ARRAY DATA **.

I have checked all the other sections, and found that if I am trying to set the value for any data type to null it is returning ** BYTE ARRAY DATA **!!!

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: *Following is the generated pstmt value:* You're seeing tha where exactly?

Comment: in the debug variable

Comment: Right, so that might be telling you that it can't display the null setting

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it will not display the null as a value!
And I have just tested and it is inserting data without any error. 
Because of other bugs, it was not inserted, I had fixed all the others and now all are working perfectly. I considered this a bug as well and wasted the last two days! 
Thanks a lot for the clarification.